# Reading dpdk output

Tags: io, traffic, dpdk

I am very new to DPDK, and this is a new project I have just been assigned to.

There is a hardware traffic generator device, connected via Ethernet to a PC. The current situation is the following:

- Send data from the traffic generator to the PC,
- DPDK receives it and then processes it accordingly,
- In the end, the data is sent back to the traffic generator.

The goal is to:

- Send data from the traffic generator to the PC,
- DPDK receives it and then processes it accordingly,
- The DPDK output is processed by a python script and then sent to the appropriate port.

The problem we've run in is finding an idea on how to get the output from DPDK since it wants to send the traffic directly to the port of the traffic generator.

Thanks in advance for the answers and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are variety of options to integrate DPDK with other applications, for example:

- Tun/tap poll mode driver: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/tap.html

  DPDK application could forward traffic to one tap vdev and poll from another. While python or other application could read packets from one kernel interface and send to another.
- KNI poll mode driver: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/kni.html

  Same as above, but using proprietary (faster) driver.
- Libpcap poll mode driver: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/pcap_ring.html

  DPDK application could send packets in pcap format to a unix socket, while python application could read the data from the socket.

Please note, all of the options listed above will not cope with more than 1M packets per second, not to mention the Python performance. It will be a challenge to process even a 1M packets...

If you need to process more than a 1M PPS, you should probably look elsewhere, there are few options...

While the question is a bit too broad, I hope now you have few hints to look for ;)